# Default permissions class for DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django rest framework currently has `IsAdminUser`as a permissions class is there also a corresponding `IsOwnerOrAdminUser`?  Something to that affect? It seems like there should be something that only allows an object to have CRUD functionality if the current user is the one that created it.  I'm using DRF with djangorestframework-jwt

Comment: Do you need a permission on object level?

Comment: That would be ideal

Comment: You said `IsOwnerOrAdminUser`. Which ower???

Comment: The user that created the object

Comment: you have to implement an object based permission.

Comment: how would you identify which user created any object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrAdminUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
       if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
          return True
       return obj.owner == request.user or request.user.is_staff
```

### views.py

```
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrAdminUser

class UserAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAdminUser, )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find full list of rest-framework permissions in [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly). There is [`DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly) which allows no-safe methods only for users with add, change and delete permissions on models.
If it's not fit your requrements you can implement your own permission class something like this:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user or request.user.is_superuser
```

This method is documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples).